# Zero inner product when using std::inner_product

Tags: c++, type-conversion, standard-library

The C++ program below should return a stricly positive value. However, it returns `0`.

What happens ? I suspect an int-double conversion, but I can't figure out why and how.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    vector<double> coordinates;
    coordinates.push_back(0.5);
    coordinates.push_back(0.5);
    coordinates.push_back(0.5);

     cout<<inner_product(coordinates.begin(), coordinates.end(), coordinates.begin(), 0)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Chuckle. That one got me once also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you've supplied an initial value of `0`, an `int`. Your code is internally equivalent to:

```
int result = 0;

result = result + 0.5 * 0.5; // first iteration
result = result + 0.5 * 0.5; // second iteration
result = result + 0.5 * 0.5; // third iteration

return result;
```

While `result + 0.5 * 0.5` produces the correct value (`result` is promoted to `double` in this expression), when that value is assigned back into `result`, it's truncated (that expression is cast to `int`). You never get above `1`, so you see `0`.

Give it an initial value of `0.0` instead.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you provided zero as an integer constant. The resultant operations are all in integers, so the final value (`0.75`) is truncated to an `int` as well.

Change zero to `0.0` to make it work:

```
cout << inner_product(coord.begin(), coord.end(),coord.begin(), 0.0) << endl;
```

This produces `0.75` on [ideone](http://ideone.com/hpD5r).

Comment: Actually, it never gets beyond 0.25 before truncking back to zero. I coined a word.