# Unable to get my software C++ glsl implementation to behave correctly

Tags: c++, math, 3d, glsl, fragment-shader

so, I am writing a couple of functions so to run GLSL fragment shaders on CPU. I implemented all the basic mathematical functions to do so. However I can't even get the simplest stuff to execute correctly. I was able to trace it down to either of these functions:

```
template<unsigned vsize>
_SHADERH_INLINE
vec<float, vsize> normalize(const vec<float, vsize>& vs) {
    vec<float, vsize> fres;
    float mod = 0.0f;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vsize; ++i) {
        mod += vs[i] * vs[i];
    }

    float mag = glsl::sqrt(mod);

    if (mag == 0) {
        std::logic_error("In normalize the input vector is a zero vector");
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vsize; ++i) {
        fres[i] = vs[i] / mag;
    }

    return fres;
}
template<unsigned vsize>
_SHADERH_INLINE
vec<float, vsize> length(const vec<float, vsize>& vs) {
    float fres = 0;
    for (unsigned it = 0; it != vsize; it++) {
        fres += vs[it] * vs[it];
    }
    return glsl::sqrt(fres);
}
template<unsigned vsize>
_SHADERH_INLINE
vec<float, vsize> dot(const vec<float, vsize>& vs1, const vec<float, vsize>& vs2) {
    return std::inner_product(vs1.begin(), vs1.end(), vs2.begin(), 0);
}
```

But it could still be something in my vec implementation (pretty certain it's not).

So, does anyone see anything wrong with the code above or something that does not align with glsl behavior? If nobody is able to find anything wrong there, I will make a follow-up question with my vec implementation.

Comment: Can you be more precise on what do you mean by "I can't even get the simplest stuff to execute" ? Is it failing to compile ? Or are the results returned by these functions wrong ? (like wrong normalized vector coordinates compared to if you calculate by hand) Or something else ?

Comment: Yup, it just results in the wrong behavior. It looks like one of the functions returns the wrong value which causes the entire shader to break and do stuff like only giving green color and nan popping up.

Comment: Is it normal that your `length` and `dot` functions return a `vec` type ? `dot` and `length` are supposed to return scalars (`float`). Or is your implementation of `vec` handling scalars as 1 component vectors ? Also in the `normalize` function, you never throw any error if `mag` is 0. You should write `throw std::logic_error(...)` instead of just `std::logic_error(...)`, otherwise I get a `(-nan, -nan, -nan)` vector if I put a null vector as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things that may be the origin of the problems.

#### Failing dot function

After a bit of testing, it turned out that your `dot` function fails, because you are providing an *integer* value `0` as initial value in your call to `inner_product`, which results in wrong calculations. See this post for the reason: [Zero inner product when using std::inner_product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065041/zero-inner-product-when-using-stdinner-product)

Simply write `0.0f` to ensure a float as initial value for the accumulator :

```cpp
vec<float, vsize> dot(const vec<float, vsize>& vs1, const vec<float, vsize>& vs2) {
    return std::inner_product(vs1.begin(), vs1.end(), vs2.begin(), 0.0f);
}
```

More generally, I recommend you to always write any hardcoded value with clear indication of its type.

You can also manually write your dot product as well, as you did in `normalize` and `length` :

```cpp
vec<float, vsize> dot(const vec<float, vsize>& vs1, const vec<float, vsize>& vs2) {
    float f = 0.0f;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vsize; ++i) {
        f += vs1[i] * vs2[i];
    }
    return f;
}
```

#### No exception thrown when normalizing a null vector

In the `normalize` function, you are not actually throwing any error when `mag == 0`. When passing a null vector to `normalize`, it returns (-nan, -nan, -nan) instead of throwing the error you want. `std::logic_error` does not throw any error, it creates an *object to be thrown* (see : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error).

Thus instead of writing :

```cpp
if (mag == 0) {
   // Doesn't do anything...
   std::logic_error("In normalize the input vector is a zero vector");
}
```

You must write :

```cpp
if (mag == 0.0f) {
   // Actually throws a `logic_error` exception
   throw std::logic_error("In normalize the input vector is a zero vector");
}
```

#### Handling of floats as `vec` types

This depends on your implementation of `vec`. `length` and `dot` return scalar values (`float`) and not vectors. Since (to my understanding) you didn't mention compilation errors, I assume your `vec` type can handle floats as 1-component vectors. Be sure that this is indeed working.

Here is the code I used to test your functions. I quickly implemented a simple `vec` class and adapted your functions to this type :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdexcept>

class vec {
    public:
        int vsize;
        std::vector<float> vals;
        
        vec(int s) : vsize(s){
            vals = std::vector<float>(vsize, 0.0f);
        }
};

void print_vec(vec& v){
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < v.vsize; i++){
        std::cout << v.vals[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

vec normalize(const vec& vs) {
    vec fres(vs.vsize);
    float mod = 0.0f;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vs.vsize; ++i) {
        mod += vs.vals[i] * vs.vals[i];
    }

    float mag = sqrt(mod);

    if (mag == 0.0f) {
        throw std::logic_error("In normalize the input vector is a zero vector");
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vs.vsize; ++i) {
        fres.vals[i] = vs.vals[i] / mag;
    }

    return fres;
}


float length(const vec& vs) {
    float fres = 0;
    for (unsigned it = 0; it != vs.vsize; it++) {
        fres += vs.vals[it] * vs.vals[it];
    }
    return sqrt(fres);
}

float dot(const vec& vs1, const vec& vs2) {
    return std::inner_product(vs1.vals.begin(), vs1.vals.end(), vs2.vals.begin(), 0.0f);
}
```

In `main` I simply tested some hardcoded vectors and printed the results of `normalize`, `length` and `dot`. I ran the code on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler